# How to create MySQL script using MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEfjYynwooE) tutorial but it seems like the queries he used in the video cannot be used in MySQL.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertIntoStudentCourses
@StudentName varchar(50), 
@CourseName varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE  @StudentId int;
  DECLARE  @CourseId int;

  SELECT @StudentId = id from Students where StudentName = @StudentName;

  if(@StudentId is null);
  Begin;
    INSERT INTO Student VALUES (@StudentName);
    SELECT @StudentId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  END;

  SELECT @CourseId = id from Courses where CourseName = @CourseName;

  if(@CourseName is null)
  BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO Courses VALUES (@CourseName);
    SELECT @CourseId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  END;

  INSERT INTO StudentCourses VALUES (@StudentID, @CourseID);
END
```

What should be the right syntax for this?

Comment: What have you tried? please post some sample code that you have tried yourself

Comment: I updated the post, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Are you seeing any error while running this script?

Comment: yes, many errors.

Comment: I'm not surprised this is sql server syntax and won't work in mysql.

Comment: that's why I'm asking for mysql version syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year of studying some [basics](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx) in creating a stored procedure in MySQL, I created my own MySQL version of the above question in like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertStudentCourse`(
    _studentName VARCHAR(50),
    _courseName VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE  _studentId INT;
    DECLARE  _courseId INT;

    SELECT _studentId = studentId FROM students WHERE studentName = _studentName;

    IF (_studentId IS NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO students VALUES (NULL, _studentName);
            SELECT _studentId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        END;
    END IF;

    SELECT _courseId = courseId FROM courses WHERE CourseName = _courseName;

    IF (_courseId IS NULL) THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO courses VALUES (NULL, _courseName);
            SELECT _courseId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        END;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO student_courses VALUES (NULL, _studentName, _courseName);
END
```